# A Connect Wall to watch and seek answers about

Tags: word, knowledge, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 words below may be separated into 4 groups.
Additionally, there is a word absent from the wall which can be placed in all four of those groups.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **DANCE** | **ENTER** | **ESCAPE** | **HEROES** |
| **INSERT** | **JACKAL** | **LETTER** | **LOW** |
| **MARRIAGE** | **NETWORK** | **PARKING** | **RETURN** |
| **SEASON** | **SOURCE** | **TENT** | **TONIGHT** |

**Can you identify the four groups?**
**What new word can be placed in all four of those groups?**

Comment: Possibly "Letter, Enter, Escape, Return" as keys on a keyboard is a good group,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The groups are

> ENTER ESCAPE INSERT RETURN = keys on a computer keyboard

> LETTER MARRIAGE SEASON SOURCE = words that can be preceded by "open"

> DANCE HEROES LOW TONIGHT = words in David Bowie record titles

> JACKAL NETWORK PARKING TENT = contain the name of a playing card (JACK, TWO, KING ,TEN)

... and the other word is

> SPACE as in the space bar, open space, the Space Oddity EP and the name of the ACE card

The title fits in because of

> WATCHING THE STARS and ASTRONOMY!

Comment: So what word can be in all of those? I'm not familiar with David Bowie album names...

Comment: Correct! Hope you will do what the title says now :)